# Issue with Git merge from development branch to feature branch is showing irrelevant changes

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm having issues with a git merge from my team's development branch to my feature branch so I can then resolve any conflicts and create a PR to merge my feature changes back to development.

The steps I did:

1. Created a feature branch off of origin/development branch.

From development branch I did: `git checkout -b feature/my_feature_branch`

2. Made my changes and commit/pushed to feature/my_feature_branch...
3. Checkout origin/development and ran: `git pull`
4. Merge development back to my feature branch to get all the latest changes with:

On feature/my_feature_branch I did: `git merge origin/development`

---

It's in this step 4 that a `git status` shows a ton of files it thinks I added or modified that are not mine (they are changes other developers made that got merged to development). See attached screenshot:

[image]

If I look at SourceTree before the merge from development I see my track (in green) hanging off of development (in blue).

[image]

If I look at SourceTree after the merge from development I see that my track (in green) has somehow now become the new main track (not sure the terminology, head?) and git thinks that development (in blue) came from my branch. Basically the two tracks, feature and development, flip.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've never had this issue before but it keeps popping up every time I merge development down to my local feature branch.

I believe I documented well what I tried and what I am expecting.

Comment: Sounds more like a suboptimal workflow. You say: "Merge development back to my feature branch to get all the latest changes." Question: Why do you do that? Do you need all the new shiny things to complete your feature?

Comment: @j6t this is a pretty standard git workflow when working with feature branches. It's mostly to resolve any conflicts before creating a PR. If your work is going to span multiple days and other coworkers are merging to develop you should do periodic merges or rebases to catch bugs or manage conflicts sooner.

Comment: This is a myth. You can do your occasional merge of other people's work to check for potential bugs that your feature branch could introduce. But then you throw away the merge if it turns out that there are no bugs. If you do find bugs, you first determine what other work leads to the badness, and then decide how to go forward; for example, to fix the problem you merge only *that* particular other feature branch. Not the whole upstream. That would be a sledgehammer.

Comment: I'm not going to get into a debate about various workflows. What I presented is super common. Did you have anything to add to the specific issue I posted here?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day this was just a standard merge conflict. I noticed that without a merge conflict Git figures out how to auto-merge all the changes on develop into your feature branch. If there's any conflict at all, Git throws its hands up in the air and forces you to manual merge by using something like mergetool or some GUI found in SourceTree or your favorite IDE. When I went through the steps of walking through each conflict and marking them as resolved I was then able to push my changes to my remote feature branch and the rest of the files auto-merged and no longer showed them coming from my branch.

I'm really not sure why I haven't come across this in such a long time but it's possible with previous teams we werea bit more silo'd with our development efforts and merge conflicts were few and far between.

tl;dr Use a merge tool to resolve the conflicts and all the changes coming from development that now show up as your changes from your feature branch will go away and be auto-merged.